Bootstrap modal component not showing up
I have this in my app.tsx:
return (
    <>
      {console.log(showModal)}
      {showModal === true && <Modal onClose={toggleModal}></Modal>}
    </>
  );

and I copied my modal component from bootstrap (I deleted the two buttons at the bottom for code simplicity):
<div className="modal" tabIndex="-1">
      <div className="modal-dialog">
        <div className="modal-content">
          <div className="modal-header">
            <h5 className="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
            <button
              type="button"
              className="btn-close"
              data-bs-dismiss="modal"
              aria-label="Close"
            ></button>
          </div>
          <div className="modal-body">
            <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

I have showModal set to true at the top of the page and even in the console it returns true but for some reason the Modal doesn't show up. I also tried it without conditional rendering just with <Modal onClose={toggleModal}></Modal> but I still got nothing.
I even tried printing to the console inside the modal component (specifically, inside the return statement) to see if it was reached, it was. I even tried to style the background of the div but I am not seeing it on my screen. I am not sure why it is not working for me.

Your debugging steps suggest that the problem is not with your React conditional rendering logic, but with your CSS? Have you checked the inspector to see if the elements are there and if the CSS classes are referencing the bootstrap stylesheet correctly?

@BrianThompson The bootstrap stylesheet seems to work for the other components and buttons on the screen. When I go into the inspector I do not see the Modal at all. Is there anything else I can check, I am fairly new to React so I am not sure of the best way to go about debugging this.
